# Displaying All EBS volumes attached to an ec2 instance via Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have attached two EBS Volumes to a EC2 instance. Using terraform, I want to output the ID's of the attached volumes. 
1. I used the Data Source "aws_instance" but it only shows One attached volume. 
2. Also tried using  Data Source "aws_ebs_volume", but still get only one volume.

Please advice.

Code:

```
*data "aws_instance" "foo" {
  instance_id = "i-kljo......b0e"
}*

*output "ebs_block_device" {
  value = "${data.aws_instance.foo.ebs_block_device}"
}*
-------------------------------------------------------
*data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Test_001"]
  }
}*

*output "ebs_all_volumnes" {
  value = ["${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"]
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

A datasource can only output **one** datasource, so only one EBS volume/datasource.

According to the [Terraform Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ebs_volume.html)

> **most_recent** - (Optional) If more than one result is returned, use the most recent Volume.
>
> **filter** - (Optional) One or more name/value pairs to filter off of. There are several valid keys, for a full reference, check out
> describe-volumes in the AWS CLI reference.

You'll have to remove the most_recent and work with filter instead. Supplying two datasources